# Как вызвать функцию через JS?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть простая функция showSecretMenu, и я вызываю её через html файл вот как-то так

> button class="dropdown" onclick="showSecretMenu()">

Объясните, как убрать *onclick="showSecretMenu()"* из html и занести в сам скрипт, чтобы оно всё не поломалось

Answer (score 3):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Button clicked!');
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="btn">ClickMe</button>
</div>
```